# Insertion Problem with Multiple-Value Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I am new to Python, so please be easy on me. I am using a dictionary to store multiple values for one key, however, I am having problems when I try to update values. Here is how I set up my dictionary; first, I write the first values using `setdefault()`:

```py
dictionary.setdefault(id.ID, []).append(id.enterTime)
dictionary.setdefault(id.ID, []).append(id.duration)
dictionary.setdefault(id.ID, []).append(id.enter)
dictionary.setdefault(id.ID, []).append(id.exit)
dictionary.setdefault(id.ID, []).append(id.standing)
dictionary.setdefault(id.ID, []).append(id.sitting)
```

For the sake of explanation, lets say that it produces the following output when printed:

```
{0: [5, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

When the id.enter instance variable is changed, I update the dictionary using the following code by just removing the original value and appending the new value to the dictionary:

```py
dictionary[id.ID].remove(id.enter)
dictionary[id.ID].insert(2, id.enter)
```

The dictionary prints as follows:

```
{0: [5, 120, 1, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Later in the program, the instance variable id.exit becomes 1. I attempted to change the exit value, after it had been updated from 0 to 1, in the dictionary as follows:

```py
dictionary[id.ID].remove(id.exit)
dictionary[id.ID].insert(3, id.exit)
```

Very bad way to do it, I know, but I thought this would be the easiest way to update the values. When I do this, a problem occurs as it changes the `id.enter` back to its original value but updates the `id.exit`:

```
{0: [5, 120, 0, 1, 0, 0]}
```

Does anyone know why this would happen? Thanks.

Comment: Why not store objects in your dict? Would be way easier to modify values. See also [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) in python 3.

Comment: `remove()` deletes the **first** value in the list that matches the argument. You passed the *new* value of `id.exit`, which is coincidentally equal to the *old* value of `id.enter` (stored at index 2, not 3). When an element is deleted from a list, all elements stored after it are shifted back by 1 space, so the new value of `id.enter` becomes the *old* value of `id.exit` (which was 0).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thank you for the information. Would this method of modifying the list work, or is this a naive way to change it?

Comment: @cz46 relying on the order of storage is a poor approach - store the `id` object directly or use a dictionary / `namedtuple` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> list.remove(x)
>   Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

So if you have the list

```
[5, 120, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

and use `remove(id.exit)`, when `id.exit` is equal to 1, then the list becomes:

```
[5, 120, 0, 0, 0]
```

As a simple solution, instead of

```
dictionary[id.ID].remove(id.exit)
dictionary[id.ID].insert(3, id.exit)
```

just use

```
dictionary[id.ID][3] = id.exit
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate that.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct and does answer the question, it would have been better to advise the user against using lists this way - those should be either tuples or dicts.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Feel free to write such an answer. I didn't want to go into full code review mode now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from use @mkrieger1 explains the problem/error with your code and gives a quick solution.

Another approach to store the data could be to use nested dicts to make it clearer and less error-prone:

```
my_dict = {
    id.ID: {
        'enterTime': id.enterTime,
        'duration': id.duration,
        'enter': id.enter,
        'exit': id.exit,
        'standing': id.standing,
        'sitting': id.sitting,
    }
}
```

Or even better with a `defaultdict`:

```
import collections
my_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {
    'enterTime': 0,
    'duration': 0,
    'enter': 0,
    'exit': 0,
    'standing': 0,
    'sitting': 0,
})
print(my_dict)
# defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f327d094ae8>, {})

# add a new ID, it creates the nested dict automatically
my_dict[object_1.ID]['exit'] = object_1.exit
print(my_dict)
# defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f327d094ae8>, {1: {'enterTime': 0, 'duration': 0, 'enter': 0, 'exit': 5, 'standing': 0, 'sitting': 0}})
```